# What's the canonical way to put a read timeout on a stream in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets

Here's some sample code:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $connectTimeout);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "connected\n"; 
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I've seen
`stream_set_timeout($fp, 5);` and
`socket_set_option($fp, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>5, "usec"=>0));`,
but the read never times out.

I've seen several caveats in the PHP docs for `stream_set_timeout()`:

> This function doesn't work with advanced operations like
>   stream_socket_recvfrom(), use stream_select() with timeout parameter instead.

I'd rather not use `select()` or a loop. What is the canonical way to have a blocking read with timeout?

Answer (score 2):

`socket_set_option` is for sockets created with `socket_create`.

`stream_set_timeout` is for streams, like created by `fopen` or `fsockopen`.

[Php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) contain example code on how it can be used with fsockopen.

Comment: Thanks. As I said in the question I'm using `fsockopen` but `stream_set_timeout($fp, 5);` does not work.